# Is there a web page with translations between Windows, Linux and MacOS keymaps/shortcuts?

Tags: intellij-idea

I don't want to apply any changes to my config. I just want to see a document where I can see all the actions and their respective shortcuts side by side, so that I can easily tell that Ctrl + W is Option + arrow up, instead of looking up what the name of the shortcut is and then looking it up for MacOS. Is there such a resource anywhere?

Comment: You can [export](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7066-keymap-exporter) different keymaps in PDFs, print, place on your table and compare side by side. Or [modify the plug-in source code](https://github.com/denis-zhdanov/intellij-plugin-export-keymap) to generate a PDF with shortcuts from multiple keymaps.

Comment: This is also quite a nice reference; https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Comment: @slindenau This is almost what I was looking for! It'll do for now. Thanks a lot.